# Decision theory when distributions don't have a first moment?

Tags: mean, random-variable, median, decision-theory, heavy-tailed

Lets say that we are presented with two gambling opportunities and would like to decide between them in a decision-theoretic framework.

For gamble 1, the cost is $1$ and the payoff is $X_1$ where $X_1 \sim \text{LogCauchy(0, 1)}$.

For gamble 2, the cost is $1$ and the payoff is $X_2$ where $X_2 \sim \text{LogCauchy(0, 2)}$.

Let's say our utility function is $\text{ln}(x)$.

If we try to use expected utility to compare these gambles, we run into a problem since both $\text{ln}(X_1)$ and $\text{ln}(X_2)$ are Cauchy-distributed and, as a result, have undefined first moments.

If we use median utility to compare these gambles, they seem like they would be equivalent since the medians of both $\text{ln}(X_1)$ and $\text{ln}(X_2)$ are $0$(?)

Both of these don't really get us anywhere and I realize other utility functions could be used, but I worry they would have similar results.

Is there a way that comparisons of this sort are generally performed? perhaps with something that combines the sensitivity of the mean with the always-defined-ness of the median?

Comment: [You have inspired me to post a question!](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/643991/247274)

Comment: Glad to inspire, @Dave ! :)

Comment: Is it clear how that question relates to this?