# What conditions are there on the exponent $p$ such that $\underset{\mu}{\arg\min}\left\{\mathbb E\left\vert X-\mu\right\vert^p\right\} $ must exist?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, optimization, expected-value

Let $X\sim F(x)$ be a (univariate) random variable defined by distribution function $F$. If the expected value exists, it is equal to $
\mathbb E[X] = \underset{\mu}{\arg\min}\left\{\mathbb E\left\vert X-\mu\right\vert^2\right\}
$.

However, the expected value does not have to exist.

What conditions are there on the exponent $p$ such that $ \underset{\mu}{\arg\min}\left\{\mathbb E\left\vert X-\mu\right\vert^p\right\}
$ must exist? How low do we have to go before it must exist? We trivially get the $\arg\min$ equal to $\mathbb R$ if $p=0$ and get the median as the $\arg\min$ for $p=1$. What about $p=1.5$ or $1.9$ or $1.99$?

I wonder if $2$ is the supremum, but not in the set, of $p$ that guarantee an $\arg\min$, and that any $p<2$ must have a defined $\arg\min$. If there is interesting commentary about uniqueness, I am on board with going down that rabbit hole.

My inspiration came from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/643877/247274), and I wonder if a reasonable answer to the linked question is to lower $p$ until the $\arg\min$ must exist.

Comment: Can you say a little more about what you mean when you say that $\textrm{argmin}...$ exists? I imagine you mean that the set of minimizers has one and only one member (for example: it is given by $\mathbb{R}$ if $p=0$)? And also: are you sure you don't want to take an absolute value before exponentiation, i.e. $|X-\mu|^p$? relevant for e.g. $p=3$. Anyways, awesome question and I can't wait to see the answers :)

Comment: @JohnMadden I have made some edits that I hope clarify my question. I’m really interested in lowering $p$ below $2$ until the $\arg\min$ must exist. I have my doubts that any $p>2$ requires the $\arg\min$ to exist (but am open to learning why that is wrong if it is).

Comment: The symmetric stable distributions don't have fractional moments $\geq$ the stability parameter, which implies $p \leq 1$ is necessary for guaranteed existence, but perhaps not necessarily sufficient?

Comment: @jbowman The median must exist, no?